# Startdrag is not a function

Tags: actionscript-3

```
this.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN,function(e:MouseEvent){this.startDrag(false,null);});
```

Hi I was wondering why the above doesnt work? Im trying to drag a sprite around screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create a sprite on stage, add instance name box, add code to frame one:

```
box.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, startMove);

function startMove(evt:MouseEvent):void {
   box.startDrag();
}

box.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, stopMove);

function stopMove(e:MouseEvent):void {
   box.stopDrag();
}
```

I think your example doesn't work because of the scope of "this" in the event listener handler.

Answer (score 0):

If you remove `this.`; it will work. It's a scope issue since you use an anonymous function.
You could use the `currentTarget` of the event, this allows you to make other boxes draggable too, if you add the same listeners.

*Note:* It is hard to remove an anonymous function as event listener and could cause memory leaks, so the best way is to use a reference to a named function:

```
box.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, handleMouseEvent);
box.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, handleMouseEvent);

function handleMouseEvent(event:MouseEvent):void 
{
    switch(event.type)
    {
       case MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN:
       {
         DisplayObject(event.currentTarget).startDrag();
         break;
       }
       case MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP:
       {
         DisplayObject(event.currentTarget).stopDrag();
         break;
       }
   }
}
```